Not able add the innerhtml to display information after recieving it from the
this the code
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Function to fetch Lost and Found posts
    function fetchLFPosts() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = "https://www-student.cse.buffalo.edu/CSE442-542/2024-Spring/cse-442z/LFGlobal.php";
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (data.LFPosts && data.LFPosts.length > 0) {
                    // console.log(data.LFPosts)
                    var postsContainer = document.getElementById('LFPostsContainer');
                    //postsContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the container before appending new posts
                    data.LFPosts.forEach(post => {
                        let postDiv = document.createElement('div');
                        postDiv.className = 'LFPost';
                        postDiv.innerHTML = '<strong>Title:</strong> ' + post.title +
                            '<br><strong>Description:</strong> ' + post.description +
                            '<br><strong>Date_of_Post:</strong> ' + post.Date_of_Post +
                            '<br><button class="delete-btn">DELETE</button>'; // Add delete button

                        // Attach event listener to delete button
                        var deleteBtn = postDiv.querySelector('.delete-btn');
                        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                            deletePost(post.postid);
                        });

                        postsContainer.appendChild(postDiv);
                    });
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('LFPostsContainer').textContent = 'No Lost and Found posts available.';
                }
            } else if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                console.error('Error fetching Lost and Found posts:', xhr.statusText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    // Call the fetchLFPosts function
    fetchLFPosts();

    function deletePost(postId) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "https://www-student.cse.buffalo.edu/CSE442-542/2024-Spring/cse-442z/deleteLFPost.php", true);

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('postId', postId)
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (response.status === "success") {
                    console.log("Lost and Found post deleted successfully");
                    alert(response.message);
                    window.location.href = 'LostAndFoundGlobal.html'
                } else {
                    console.error('Error deleting Lost and Found post:', response.message);
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
});

The plan was to get data from the php and add to the html page. I am getting the data but it is not diaplaying the data on the html page.I Have checked and confimred the div and class names are accurate. There are no errors so don't know what is going wrong
I have already put the console.log to see if the loop is run which it does. the problem has been narrowed down to from perspective to the innnerhtml part. Wanted to know if there is an alternate method to show the data

It's the 2020's you should learn to use fetch() instead of XMLHttpRequest.

we were initailly using fetch but that was not working so had to use XMLHttpRequest

I'm getting a CORS error when I try your script. Are you getting that error in the console?

We were but manged to fix that. we have                                                    header("https://www-student.cse.buffalo.edu/CSE442-542/2024-Spring/cse-442z/");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); to help with the errors in php

It's not likely that switching from fetch to XMLHttpRequest will fix anything. You should figure out what was causing the problem and fix that.

What about Access-Control-Allow-Origin:?

We did figure it out. we think it is the inner html part as we get data back but not able to display it

I did not get get your last question

You need header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <something>");

When I remove the AJAX code and hard-code the JSON, your code works for me.  https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/kb0a2fng/ So the problem is with the AJAX.

we have that header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

That's not Access-Control-Allow-Origin. You need that header to indicate what domain is allowed to call this API.

If you don't want to restrict access, use header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Thank you. Me and my group were stuck on this for 3 days

Many use XHR for tracking progress. @Barmar

@BGPHiJACK Good point. It's needed for upload progress, but not download progress

we changed to a fetch and it is same as before. Can u suggest how to fix it

Is inspect element displaying these items possibly a style misconfiguration? You suggest no error so things would had been appended.
